# Retrieving favicon as icon instead of image

Tags: c#, image, browser, icons, favicon

I used the favicon-code I found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60179/Web-Browser-in-C#Howtogetthefaviconofawebsite2) to retrieve the favicon of the site loaded in the browser element.

I want to use this favicon as the icon of my Windows Form.

Thanks to [JP Hellemons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169714/jp-hellemons) this code works:

```
private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
    this.Icon = favicon(GetActiveBrowser().Url);
}

private WebBrowser GetActiveBrowser() {
    return (WebBrowser)tabs.SelectedTab.Controls[0];
}

private Icon favicon(Uri url) {
    WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + url.Host + "/favicon.ico");

    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(32, 32);
    MemoryStream memStream;

    using (Stream response = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()) {
        memStream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int byteCount;

        do {
            byteCount = response.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
        } while (byteCount > 0);
    }

    bm = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(memStream));

    if (bm != null) {
        Icon ic = Icon.FromHandle(bm.GetHicon());
        return ic;
    } else
        return Properties.Resources.GZbrowser;
}
```

Comment: Re your "Visual C#" question: C# is C#. I guess you can say "Visual" if you use the Visual Studio IDE mostly in graphic design mode, but there is no "Visual C#" vs "Other kinds of C#", like there is with Basic.

Comment: @MrLister: OK thanks, It's because i've red a lot of tuts wich mention Visual C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this documentation, it should work from stream.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.aspx

I used this article: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2004/10/05/webrequest-and-binary-data.aspx

```
WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + url.Host + "/favicon.ico");
Icon ic = new Icon(); // put default here
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap();

try
{
    using(WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
       using(Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
       {
          using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
          {
              var tmp = Image.FromStream(ms); // changed bitmap to image
              bm = new Bitmap(tmp);
          }
       }
    }
}catch{}
if(bm != null)
{
    ic = Icon.FromHandle(bm.GetHicon);  
}
return ic;
```

**Edit:** something like this should do it

**Edit2:** changed some things in the answer. Can you try this?

**Final edit:** (lol)

Just tested this in a windows form app and this works! :)

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.google.nl");
WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + url.Host + "/favicon.ico");

Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(32,32); 
MemoryStream memStream;

using (Stream response = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    memStream = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int byteCount;

    do
    {
        byteCount = response.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        memStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
    } while (byteCount > 0);
}

bm = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(memStream));                 

if (bm != null) 
{
    Icon ic = Icon.FromHandle(bm.GetHicon());
    this.Icon = ic;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  
  
I've tweeked you code a little bit, as returning wouldn't work (I had to create a new Icon) + I wanted to use my own favicon in case the site didn't have one.  
  
Sadly, I still get an error: **Argument picture must be an image that can be used as an Icon**  
  
See my code in the next post

Comment: The new version gives me this error in VS: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

Comment: Using _(Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);_ and a MessageBox in the catch results in the following error: **Invalid parameter at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(....) ... on rule 340**

Rule 339-341:
'using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
       bm = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
      }'

Comment: That is because the ico contains multiple bitmaps, more about it here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/130238-C-20-convert-Bitmap-to-Icon-problem

Comment: So [this code](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/130238-C-20-convert-Bitmap-to-Icon-problem/ddf141243a4a4301b2839dea012f1081) should do?
' System.IO.Stream outputStream;

            Icon tIco;
            
            Bitmap tBmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

            outputStream = System.IO.File.Create(@textBox2.Text);
            tIco = Icon.FromHandle(tBmp.GetHicon());
            tIco.Save(outputStream);
            
            outputStream.Close(); '

Comment: Still don't get how I can use that code in my current code :s

Comment: Can you update your question, to show how far you are and what the current error is

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you VERY much. Hartelijk dank!

Comment: Nice, can you accept the answer so that the question is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Read response byte array first, than create MemoryStream of it and create icon from that MemoryStream.

Network stream do not support seek operations that seem to be necessary for creating an icon.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. But I don't now much about working with Streams etc. I'm a beginner in C#. Could you help me out with some code examples? I'm not asking for the full code (but I won't stop you from doing it anyway :p), but some code would be usefull